# Click button by class

Tags: javascript

I want to click a `Like` button that have these properties:

```
<span class="_49vh _2pi7">Like</span>
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work in this case:

```
<script>
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_49vh _2pi7');
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length;) {
    inputs[i].click();
  }
</script>
```

**Note:** In my HTML page I just one `Like` button.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `i++` increment in for loop

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_49vh _2pi7');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].click=check
  inputs[i].click();
}
function check(){
console.log('clicked')
}
```

```html
<span class="_49vh _2pi7">Like</span>
```

Comment: @J-rone if this answer was helpful for you, consider approving it

Answer (score 0):

As you have only one element directly use `.click()` and also `querySelector()` can be used to retrieve element

```
document.querySelector('._49vh._2pi7').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's work`

```
<span class="_49vh_2pi7">Like</span>`

<script>
$('._49vh_2pi7').on('click',function(){
   /////do somthing here.
});
</script>
```

Comment: This adds an event handler to the span, it doesn't click it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `i++` in the for loop. If you change the loop from `for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;)` to `for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)` and it will work fine.

Another, much easier method is to use the jQuery library. Then you can simply write `$("._49vh._2pi7").click()` (`._49vh._2pi7` is the CSS selector for the button).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you that like button is not from Cross Origin (Facebook, Google or from different domain and not inside the Cors Iframe).
You can't access cross origin elements in an iframe.